# How does one access datagridview components when data is preloaded in?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to be able to access the table so that I can add DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode to fill, and also so that I can access the rest of the table so that I can code add, edit and remove buttons that access the database.

I'm just not sure how to do it because I'm unfamiliar with databases, loading them and saving them

```
'Declarations
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT * FROM Items"
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con)

'Opening Load
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    con.Open()

    da.Fill(ds, "ItemsTable")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("ItemsTable")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ig you are asking for a tutorial in db programming, you have asked in the wrong place.  This is far too broad for this site.  It is something you can and should research on your own

Comment: I've already researched on how to do the above, but mainly my problem is accessing the table, with that, I can code the rest of it.  All the ones that I've researched have their tables hardcoded in then filled manually with sql.

Comment: The table is in the DataSet

Comment: Pardon, still not entirely used to talking with database and vb terms. By table, I meant the datagridview. I can't seem to access the datagridview's columns, nor other settings while the data isn't loaded in yet.

Comment: Check out the Microsoft documentation for DataAdapter.Update (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx)